# How to insert a value in an array field inside mongodb collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, http, post, nosql

I want to insert a string in an array of strings that is present in a mongodb collection.
the collection looks like:

```
{
   "_id": some id,
   "urls": [url1,url2]
}
```

I want to insert a string on every insert call to the urls array
How can I do it?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "insert call to the urls array."   Do you want to, for example, take `[url1,url2]` and turn it into `[url1,newInsertString,url2]`?

Comment: Yes,That only..

Answer (score 0):

The `$push` operator changed some time back to allow an array of 1 to n items to be inserted into an existing array at an arbitrary position:

```
db.foo.find();
{ "_id" : 0, "items" : [ "url1", "url2" ] }

// Position starts at 0.  Let's use position 1 for the demo:
db.foo.update({_id:0},{$push: {"items": {$each: ["foo","bar"], $position: 1}}});

db.foo.find();
{ "_id" : 0, "items" : [ "url1", "foo", "bar", "url2" ] }
```

Note that position can also be negative.  -1 is the end of the array, -2 is 1 item in from the end, etc.  To insert something into the `items` array in every doc, provide the `{}` predicate and `multi:true` option:

```
db.foo.update({},{$push: {"items": {$each: ["foo","bar"], $position: 1}}},{multi:true});
```

Answer (score -1):

your post request, with express.js for example, will look something like this:

```
const urlRouter = express.Router();
urlRouter.route('/your_route_here').post((req, res, next) => {
    yourMongoCollectionSchema.create(req.body)
    .then(url => {
        console.log("Url added", url);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(url);
    }, err => next(err))
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
```